# AJAX On Success not working Sequential

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check my for loop when end therefore I'm using **console.log()**
for print sequence like **(0,1,2,3,4)**  but I have got only **(0,1,3,4)** after ajax on success call then It's print **(2)** What's wrong in my code **IDK** please help me.

```
for (var index = 0; index < TotalEmployee.length; index++) {

    console.log('0');

    if ($(TotalEmployee[index]).children('span').find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {

        for (var index_1 = 0; index_1 < TotalPayHead.length; index_1++) {

            console.log('1');

            if ($(TotalPayHead[index_1]).children('span').find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
                $.ajax({
                    ////Ajax Code
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
                function OnSuccess(response) {
                    let TotalEmp = $('#lstEmployee div');
                    let TotalPay = $('#lstPayHead div');
                    console.log('2');
                    console.log(index_1, TotalPay.length);
                    console.log(index, TotalEmp.length);

                    if (index_1 == TotalPay.length) {
                        if (index == TotalEmp.length) {

                            $.unblockUI();
                            alertProvider();
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log('3');
            }
        }
        console.log('4');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the correct behaviour. It's ajax call, so by the time `success` call back gets the value from backend, your rest of the code executes. It's the expected behavior.

Comment: async :false may be work for you

Comment: AJAX=Asynchronous Javascript And Xml. So it is the default behavior. As Minesh said you can try async:false.

Comment: use `async :false`  but not recommended

Comment: any other solution instead of  **async:false**

Comment: There is no other way but execute your rest of the sequence after ajax callback, if you are stuck that means your'e logic is wrong so try to alter your code so that you don't face this issue.

Comment: Yo might be stuck in `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem`